# Can't Set SwiftUI ScrollViewReader Scrolling Animation Speed

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, scrollviewreader

In a SwiftUI app with SwiftUI flow for iOS15, I'm trying to slow the animation of the
ScrollViewReader scrolling speed. Clearly in the example below, the scrolling does
not take 100 seconds. While the animation in this example is visually ok, in the real
app I am programmatically calling the scrollTo and it is almost immediate and
totally looks jerky. Am I missing something?

Here's an example:

```
struct ListView: View {

    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]
    @State private var shouldChangeRow: Bool = false
    @State private var number: Int = 100

    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<number) { i in
                        Text("Row \(i)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 50)
                            .background(colors[i % colors.count])
                            .id(i)
                    }//for each
                }//list
                .onChange(of: shouldChangeRow) { _ in
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 100)) {
                        proxy.scrollTo(Int.random(in: 0..<number), anchor: .top)
                    }
                }//on change
            }//reader
            .frame(height: 500)
        
            Button("Change") {
                withAnimation {
                    shouldChangeRow.toggle()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .padding()

        }//v
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15

Comment: It is known behavior, `scroll to` uses own internal animation, we have no possibility to affect it now.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks.